# Kotlin Coroutine - Ktor Server WebSocket

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I made a kotlin-ktor application, what i wanted to achieve is that it is modular that anytime any pipelines inside the application maybe removed from the source code without breaking any functionalities. So i decided i want to move a websocket implementation to separate class

but i faced an issue where the coroutine inside the lambda expression terminates immediately.
[link-github issue](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1350)

Can someone enlighten me about the coroutine setup on this, and how I can still keep this as modular without this kind of issue

**working ktor websocket**

```
fun Application.socketModule() = runBlocking {

   // other declarations
    ......

    routing {
        val sessionService = SocketSessionService()
        webSocket("/home") {
            val chatSession = call.sessions.get<ChatSession>()
            println("request session: $chatSession")

            if (chatSession == null) {
                close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.VIOLATED_POLICY, "empty Session"))
                return@webSocket
            }
            send(Frame.Text("connected to server"))
            sessionService.addLiveSocket(chatSession.id, this)
            sessionService.checkLiveSocket()
        }

        thread(start = true, name = "socket-monitor") {
            launch {
                sessionService.checkLiveSocket()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**kotlin-ktor auto-close web socket**

code below closes the socket automatically

***Socket Module***

```
class WebSocketServer {

    fun createWebSocket(root: String, routing: Routing) {
        println("creating web socket server")
        routing.installSocketRoute(root)
    }

    private fun Routing.installSocketRoute(root: String) {
        val base            = "/message/so"
        val socketsWeb      = SocketSessionService()

        webSocket("$root$base/{type}") {

            call.parameters["type"] ?: throw Exception("missing type")
            val session = call.sessions.get<ChatSession>()

            if (session == null) {
                println( "WEB-SOCKET:: client session is null" )
                close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.VIOLATED_POLICY, "No Session"))
                return@webSocket
            }

            socketsWeb.addLiveSocket(session.id, this)

            thread(start= true, name = "thread-live-socket") {
                launch {
                    socketsWeb.checkLiveSocket()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Application Module***

```
fun Application.socketModule() = runBlocking {
   // other delcarations
   .....
    install(Sessions) {
        cookie<ChatSession>("SESSION")
    }

    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features) {
        if (call.sessions.get<ChatSession>() == null) {
            val sessionID = generateNonce()
            println("generated Session: $sessionID")
            call.sessions.set(ChatSession(sessionID))
        }
    }

    routing {
        webSocketServer.createWebSocket("/home", this)
   }
}
```

I quite dont understand why the coroutine insdie **webSocket** lamda is completed.
Can someone show me other/right approach on this one.